# Oak Leaf Blister (Taphrina caerulescens)

Tags: diagnosis, tree-care, oak

I'm pretty certain my oak has *[Taphrina caerulescens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taphrina_caerulescens)* symptoms. There is yellow bulbs on it since the beginning of the summer. Can it endanger the tree health? How can it be cured?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe these are more likely to be [oak galls](http://www.sfrc.ufl.edu/extension/4h/foresthealth/stress/galls.html). This is not an issue for oaks. It is commonly found on oaks and no action is required.

Even if it is the problem you describe, Taphrina, the Wikipedia links indicates that "Watering and fertilizing infected trees can help reduce stress on the tree and can reduce disease symptoms".

You can never go wrong watering your trees during dry times.